# How to set record rules in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I want add two groups for project.tak :

the first can read and write records if condition1 and only read the others 
the second can read and write if not condition1 and only read if condition1 how i can do this with ir_rule

when I put the condition in domain_force and i make (read,write,create,unlink)=(1,1,0,0) he does not work